# XF Shell navigate to the same page

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-shell

I need a little advice on navigating the Xamarin Forms Shell. I'm trying to create a page with details. Navigation to the detail page works, but unfortunately the go back no longer works. See gif. Someone where I make a mistake would advise me. Thanks a lot.

My navigation code:

```
    GoToCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
    {
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(this.TextEntry));

        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(DetailPage)}?detailtext={this.TextEntry}");

        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("DetailPage");
    });

    GoBackCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
    {
        await Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync();

        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    });
```

Source code:
https://filebin.net/nhkar968g5hj7e9m/ShellNavigationTest.rar?t=ctq0geqi

[image]

Comment: You should use PushAsync instead of GotoAsync if your are willing to use PopAsync after

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work either. Going to the page works, not back. The back button does not respond. When I use Shell.Current.Navigation.PopAsync or GoToAsync ("..") the application crashes.

Comment: what is the error/exception that causing the crash ?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hkSX1zo.png   System.ArgumentException: 'Ambiguous routes matched for: //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem4/IMPL_HomePage/HomePage/D_FAULT_DetailPage8/D_FAULT_DetailPage9 matches found: //D_FAULT_FlyoutItem4/IMPL_HomePage/HomePage/D_FAULT_DetailPage8/D_FAULT_DetailPage9,//D_FAULT_FlyoutItem4/IMPL_HomePage/HomePage/D_FAULT_DetailPage8/D_FAULT_DetailPage9
Parameter name: uri'

Comment: I use XF - 5.0.0.2012

Comment: It looks like the problem in XF itself https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13611

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation#backwards-navigation) you should be able to use this here:

```cs
await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
```